Do authentication in a Laravel system for the routes in api.php, which if it fails will return a json
I want the routes within this group:
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {

In case of failure, return a json, and not a view like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html lang="es" dir="">


<head>

    <title>
        Laravel
        - Iniciar sesión
    </title>

How to return a json when Sanctum authentication fails in Laravel for an API

have you set headers  in ajax or axios .   content type and accept as application/json

as JohnLobo said, you need to add the header Accept: application/json even in your postman. This will prevent the redirection and promt a json response.

You need to customize the response for unauthenticated users. This can be achieved by adding or modifying the unauthenticated method in the app/Exceptions/Handler.php file.
 protected function unauthenticated(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json([
              'message' => 'Unauthenticated.',
              'exception' => $exception->getMessage()
            ], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
    }

Also ensure that the requests to these routes are properly set to expect a JSON response by setting the Accept header to application/json and actually returning a json response when there is an authorization exception.

Sanctum already does that. a request need the header accept:application/json to be identified as $request->expectsJson().
